# Python: How to fix random seed inside process?

Tags: python, random, process, python-multiprocessing, random-seed

I want to make each process produce random numbers but I want them be reproducible across runs.

Here is example code:

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Process

random.seed(2019)

def f2():
    print('from f2:')
    v = random.randint(0, 10)
    a = random.randint(0, 10)
    print('v:', v)
    return v, a


def python_process_test():
    n_workers = 2
    workers = []
    for i in range(n_workers):
        p = Process(target=f2, args=())
        p.start()
        workers.append(p)

    for p in workers:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    python_process_test()
```

This is not desired behaviour, because values are not the same across runs:

run 1:

```
from f2:
v: 6
from f2:
v: 4
```

run 2:

```
from f2:
v: 0
from f2:
v: 5
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process

random.seed(2019)

def get_random_sleep_time_v1():
    return random.randint(0,3)

def get_random_sleep_time_v2():
    from datetime import datetime
    random.seed(datetime.now())
    return random.randint(0,3)

def f2(rnd_seed, process_id):
    random.seed(rnd_seed)

    # To rundomize order in which process will print
    sleep_time = get_random_sleep_time_v1()
    #sleep_time = get_random_sleep_time_v2()
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    print('process_id:', process_id)
    v = random.randint(0, 10)
    a = random.randint(0, 10)
    print('v:', v)
    return v, a


def python_process_test():
    n_workers = 4
    workers = []
    for i in range(n_workers):
        rnd_seed = random.randint(0,10)
        p = Process(target=f2, args=(rnd_seed,i))
        p.start()
        workers.append(p)

    for p in workers:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    python_process_test()
```

Using `get_random_sleep_time_v1` I get desired behaviour but order of processes not changing from run to run:

```
run 1:

    process_id: 0
    v: 1
    process_id: 3
    v: 1
    process_id: 1
    v: 9
    process_id: 2
    v: 2

run 2:

    process_id: 0
    v: 1
    process_id: 3
    v: 1
    process_id: 1
    v: 9
    process_id: 2
    v: 2
```

Using `get_random_sleep_time_v2` order of processes is random but generated values are not consistent across runs:

```
run 1:
process_id: 3
v: 10
process_id: 1
v: 8
process_id: 2
v: 7
process_id: 0
v: 6

run 2:
process_id: 0
v: 8
process_id: 3
v: 10
process_id: 2
v: 10
process_id: 1
v: 8
```

Comment: In what regard does this differ from your expectations?

Comment: @FredLarson see update.

Comment: So do you still have a question, or did you edit your solution into the question (which should be an answer)?

Comment: @FredLarson at the top "I want to make each process produce random numbers but I want them be reproducible across runs."

Comment: In your last version you're reseeding the RNG when you call `get_random_sleep_v2()`, and that affects the random number sequence.

Comment: If you want to make the sleep time random but still use `rnd_seed`, put `random.seed(rnd_seed)` after the call to `get_random_sleep_v2()`.

Comment: Just a heads up: if you're using functions from "numpy" to generate your random numbers, use `numpy.random.seed()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the seed inside your processes:

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f2(i):
    random.seed(2019+i)
    print('from f2:')
    v = random.randint(0, 10)
    a = random.randint(0, 10)
    print('v:', v, 'a:', a)
    return v, a


def python_process_test():
    n_workers = 2
    workers = []

    for i in range(n_workers):
        p = Process(target=f2, args=([i]))
        p.start()
        workers.append(p)

    for p in workers:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    python_process_test()
```

This yield the following output everytime:

```
from f2:
v: 2 a: 3
from f2:
v: 9 a: 9
```

EDIT: updated to show the passthrough of reseeding each process by worker with different seeds

Comment: Why is this necessary? There are other questions asking how to get *different* random sequences when using multiprocessing, they say that the processes all inherit the same RNG state.

Comment: This was changed as part of python 3.7,  see https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/346cbd351ee0dd3ab9cb9f0e4cb625556707877e#diff-3f5f2db4a1121be5be6b07b5a52b0b09 and more specifically https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/346cbd351ee0dd3ab9cb9f0e4cb625556707877e#diff-3214ef7af90d7b293fa0c247390ec5fe The child process get a new random seed by default

Comment: I reproduced the OP's result using Python 3.6.3.

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9650#issuecomment-327150506 "Python 3.6's default behavior of reseeding in the child processes was hard-coded in the _launch method of multiprocessing.popen_fork.Popen and is specific to the built-in random module" - going through the thread as well: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9650#issuecomment-327154876 "In 3.5 random is not reseeding but is using a shared state across workers."

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Process
from datetime import datetime

random.seed(2222)

def get_random_sleep_time():
    random.seed(datetime.now().microsecond)
    return random.randint(0,3)

def f2(rnd_seed, process_id):
    # To randomize order in which process will print
    sleep_time = get_random_sleep_time()
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

    random.seed(rnd_seed)

    v = random.randint(0, 10)
    a = random.randint(0, 10)
    print('process_id:', process_id, 'v:', v)
    return v, a

def python_process_test():
    n_workers = 4
    workers = []
    for i in range(n_workers):
        rnd_seed = random.randint(0,10)
        p = Process(target=f2, args=(rnd_seed,i))
        p.start()
        workers.append(p)

    for p in workers:
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    python_process_test()
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple fix, so no worries:

**If you want to generate the same number every time you need to pass the same seed value every time. [1](https://pynative.com/python-random-seed/)**

So all you need to do is call `random.seed(2019)` before every `randint()`.

Essentially, every time you use the random module to obtain a value, it pulls the `.seed()` value from the current system time. So you'll have to manually set the seed each time, or else it'll default back to that behavior.

Comment: If you keep resetting the seed, you just keep getting the same number. You only need to seed before the first call.